# Bootstrap slider conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two instances of a bootstrap carousel on my page. I am using the code below to randomize the slides on page refresh for the first carousel.

```
//randomize the slider on page load 
var $item = $('.carousel .item');  
$item.eq(0).addClass('active'); 

var $numberofSlides = $('.item').length;
var $currentSlide = Math.floor((Math.random() * $numberofSlides));

$('.carousel-indicators li').each(function(){ 
  var $slideValue = $(this).attr('data-slide-to'); 
  if($currentSlide == $slideValue) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $item.eq($slideValue).addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $item.eq($slideValue).removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

However, since I have two carousels on the page. This code is causing one of them to not always load when refreshing the page. How can i only target one carousel using the code above? Can i add an ID to one of them and incorporate that somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some simple changes you can make to your script to do this for EACH carousel:

```
//Do this for each .carousel
$(".carousel").each(function () { 
    //randomize the slider on page load
    //Find .item within the current .carousel
    var $item = $(this).find('.item');
    $item.eq(0).addClass('active'); 

    //Find .item within the current .carousel
    var $numberofSlides = $(this).find('.item').length;
    var $currentSlide = Math.floor((Math.random() * $numberofSlides));

    //Find .carousel-indicators li within the current .carousel
    $(this).find('.carousel-indicators li').each(function(){
        var $slideValue = $(this).attr('data-slide-to'); 
        if($currentSlide == $slideValue) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $item.eq($slideValue).addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $item.eq($slideValue).removeClass('active');
        }
    }); 
});
```

(I've added some comments before the lines I have added and changed)

If you just want to do this for one carousel, then yes you should give it an ID so you can target it.

```
//randomize the slider on page load
var $item = $('#carouselid .item');
$item.eq(0).addClass('active'); 

var $numberofSlides = $('#carouselid .item').length;
var $currentSlide = Math.floor((Math.random() * $numberofSlides));

$('#carouselid .carousel-indicators li').each(function(){
    var $slideValue = $(this).attr('data-slide-to'); 
    if($currentSlide == $slideValue) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $item.eq($slideValue).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $item.eq($slideValue).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

In the three places I have typed `carouselid`, you would replace this with the ID you assign the carousel.